# DataTable in C# - List type of column and Add method

Tags: c#, datatable

I created empty DataTable `myDT` and one of the columns, say `Column3` has type `List<double>`. Now in my code I would like to add sth like this:

```
myDT.Rows[0]["Column3"].Add(100)
```

But I can't use `Add` method here. What can I do instead? I would like to add elements from different pieces of code to the list in a this specific cell.

Answer (score 3):

Because of [`DataTable.Rows[][]`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/DataRow.cs,247) might return `object` type instance instead of `List<double>` we need to convert the type as your original type `List<double>` before call `Add` method.

In your case, I would use `as` to try to cast the object to your expected type, if that type is `List<double>` the `list` will not be null. make sure our code is safer.

```
var list = dt.Rows[0]["dd"] as List<double>;
if (list != null)
{
    list.Add(100);
}
```

Comment: *"make sure our code is safer"* -- I am not sure that the definition of "safer" includes code that produces incorrect results. If the "dd" column doesn't contain `List<double>` objects, it's probably better for the application to crash loudly with an error message, than to say to the user "OK, your changes have been saved" without having saved anything.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I mean we can use some custom handler in `else` scope after the if statement because we expected `"dd"` is `List<double>` if not we might want to do something instead of getting an exception in my opinion,

Comment: The exceptions exist for cases exactly like this IMHO. If my application expects that the column "dd" contains `List<double>` objects, and the actual data are, say, strings, something has gone horribly wrong. That's something exceptional, not normal. You can't realistically handle cases like this, without propagating an exception to the caller.

Answer (score 3):

If You are using C# 8.0+ version, then you can use [`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) with [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/pattern-matching), like

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["Column3"] is List<double> Column3)
{
    Column3.Add(100);
}
```

Comment: Nice one, C# 8.0+ version, Pattern Matching clear than the older version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.Field` instead.

```
myDT.Rows[0].Field<List<double>>("Column3").Add(100)
```

Comment: +1. This is the best answer IMHO. It should be mentioned that in case the data in the particular row/column is `DBNull.Value`, the `Field<List<double>>("Column3")` call will return `null`.